# how can i print two digit number up to 99 and three digit number 999 to 100 using one text box?

Tags: javascript, html

i am newer to developer solving this problem i am not getting three digit number up to 100. when i am giving in between 999 to 100 to print up to 100.

this is my html code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="logic.js"></script> 
<input type="text" id="number">
<input type="button" onClick="logic()" Value="choice" />
```

this is my javascript..

```
function logic() {
    var number = document.getElementById("number").value;   
    if(number.length<=99){
        for(var i=number;i<=99;i++){
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
    else if(number.length<=999){
        for(var j=number;j>=100;j--){
            console.log(j);
        }           
    }    
}
```

if i am giving in between 10 to 99 to print up to 99 and 999 to 100 to print up to 100  so please help me...

Answer (score 1):

You will get a type of string from the input.

You have to change it to a type of number to compare it to a number.

`parseInt()`

`.length` is an array and string property. That is why you get unexpected numbers.

It seems that you need to do a course on programming and java script.

Roughly as a start maybe this is what you wanted to create until some point.

```
function logic()
{
  var number = parseInt ( document.getElementById("number").value );

  if(number <= 99)

  {
     for(var i=number;i<=99;i++)
     {
       console.log(i);
     }
  }
  else if(number <= 999 && number > 99 ){

      for(var j=number;j>=100;j--)
      {
        console.log(j);
      } 

  }
}
```

Comment: if i am giving 55 in text box it prints the 55 to 99 and if i give 888 it prints the 888 to 100 like that i want

Comment: It would have been better if you figure this out yourself. I encourage you to study more.